# ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000 on OmniSharp install in Visual Studio Code on WSL2 behind corporate cloud proxy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, omnisharp, zscaler

I have Visual Studio Code operating with Remote WSL 2 on Ubuntu 20.04 (on a Win10 box behind a corporate firewall) and wanted to install the C# extension.

On addition of the extension and each time I entered VS Code / WSL 2 on that particular workspace, the extension is not able to install the required OmniSharp & Co. packages:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking several other posts I found the `NO_PROXY` environment variable, which does the trick when placed in `.profile`.

Steps:

1. add to your `~/.profile` on WSL2:

```
export NO_PROXY=roslynomnisharp.blob.core.windows.net,vsdebugger.blob.core.windows.net,razorvscodetest.blob.core.windows.net
```

2. close and start Visual Studio Code with Remote WSL again in the designated workspace